# Passing JSON Parameters into the Azure DevOps Powershell Script

Tags: string, powershell, azure-devops

I'm trying to pass my variable into my JSON post parameters, however, the below code only works for hardcoding the values, but I need to pass the `$var` to the `principal` parameter:

```
$var="demo"

Write-Host $var


$postParams = @'
{   "scope": "DemoScope","principal": "$($var)" }
'@
```

So far I tried like `$(var)` and `$($var)` in the above script but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use `' '` the variable can't be used, I like this way to create the json:

```
$postParams = @{
    scope = "DemoScope"
    principal = $var
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Result:
{
    "principal": "demo",
    "scope": "DemoScope"
}
```

Another way it to use `"` instaed of `'`:

```
$postParams = @"
{    "scope": "DemoScope","principal": "$var" }
"@
```